# Single page website and vertical alignment in one div only

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

On my site http://goo.gl/16XdA page "contact us" I'd like the contact-box to be vertically aligned within the container div "contact us". The issue is that with the current code the contact-box gets aligned in the middle of the 1400px height of "contact us" div. Is there a way to align the contact box to the middle of the screen no matter what the screen resolution is? (or put a 100% height for the contact-us div but that did not work)

```
#contact-us {
    height: 1400px;
    background: #8aba56;
    padding-top: 250px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/bg-water13.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#contact-box {
    text-align:center;
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 300px;
    Height:120px;
    padding:15px;
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: 0.85; /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border: 1px dotted #666;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the height for `#contact-us` to `100%`, *as well as its parent elements* (html and body), and remove its padding:

```
html, body, #contact-us {
    height: 100%;
}

#contact-us {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great. Would it make sense to put a height of 100% to all my #div? In the tutorial based on which I built my website they were suggesting to use a height of more than 1200px. But now that I'm thinking about it, it makes more sense to use 100% all the time, right?

Comment: I would try to make it at least `100%` height, but it should be able to expand if that section has more content than can fit in the height of the browser (in the case a user's screen is particularly small). Maybe `min-height`?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your site on chrome it is in the center of #contact-us. However contact-us is  1650 pixels high because you added 250 px padding so the div is at the center of the 1400 box but 250 px is being added to the top location.

You can fix this by changing the box-sizing to border-box or increase the margin-top.